# Bundled notification replaces the first notification

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications, kotlin-android-extensions

When creating a bundled notification using setGroup() and setGroupSummary() I am having some strange issues regarding the behaviour of the notifications.

So, as a reference. This example contains the issue:

```
        var isFirstNotificationInGroup = true

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            notificationManager.activeNotifications.forEach {
                if (it.notification.group == groupId) {
                    isFirstNotificationInGroup = false
                }
            }
        }

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId).apply {
            color = resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent)
            priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_dotoo_logo)
            setContentTitle(title)
            setContentText(body)
            setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(body))
            setAutoCancel(true)
            setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SOCIAL)
            setGroup(groupId)
            setGroupSummary(isFirstNotificationInGroup)
        }

        < ... >

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
            notify(notificationId, builder.build())
        }
```

**What happens?**

The first notification will be shown as it should. So no issues here.
Then, when we show the second notification. It replaces the first one. This shouldn't happen. *And no, it is not due to the notification ID. That's not related to this as far as I know.*

But, when we show a third (or more) notification, the bundle works as expected and shows two (or more) bundled notifications. But the first one is... gone.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by creating a seperate summary notification when isFirstNotificationInGroup is true. 
This will be send just before the 'real' notification will be send.